# WP7 limit of background agent

Tags: windows-phone-7, limit, agent

I [read](http://www.mywindowsphone.net/137/background-task-on-windows-phone-have-a-limit) that WP7 limits the number of background agents.

Does this limit include audio player agent, file transfer agent, ... or only periodic agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is written there:

Multi tasking basically comprises of these functions, **each** have **a limit independently**:

- Background Agents
- Background **File Transfer**
- Background **Audio Playback**
- Scheduled Notifications
- Fast Application Switching

Comment: do you know how long does Audio player agent live?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.92).aspx  See the *Memory and Runtime Constraints*

Comment: I read that calling NotifyComplete only dispose AudioPlayer, not the process it live in. The fact is that some static variables still alive

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/11/23/leveraging-background-services-and-agents-in-windows-phone-7-mango.aspx good page to read.